# Convert entire HTML theme to current WordPress

Tags: html, wordpress, wordpress-theming, material-design, themes

I have a theme along with every CSS and JavaScript file. I wanted to apply the HTML theme to my WordPress site. However, I do not need any content from my WordPress to be removed or change from their respective locations.

Is there any way that I can migrate my HTML theme to my WordPress without losing the contents and plugins.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the only solution to this is to manually redesign the WordPress website so it will be like your html theme (or hire a designer to do that for you).